# JQuery Selector with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to retrieve my JSON values to my autocomplete table row using the following:

Javascript:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var text2 = $("#Text2").tautocomplete({
                width: "500px",
                columns: ['id', 'title'],
                ajax: {
                    url: "products.json",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: function () {
                        return [{ test: text2.searchdata() }];
                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                        var filterData = [];

                        var searchData = eval("/" + text2.searchdata() + "/gi");

                        $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                            if (v.products.search(new RegExp(searchData)) != -1) {
                                filterData.push(v);
                            }
                        });
                        return filterData;
                    }
                },
                onchange: function () {
                    $("#ta-txt").html(text2.text());
                    $("#ta-id").html(text2.id());
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**products.json**:

```
 {"products":[[{"id":"1","country":"Photobooks"},{"id":"2","country":"Cards"}]]}
```

and I'm getting this error:
***TypeError: v.products is undefined***

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what products.json returns to the variable `data`, there is no `v.products` in your loop. There is `data.products` which is an array with one node which is an array of your results. Take a look:

```
{"products":
    [
        [
            {
                "id":"1",
                "country":"Photobooks"
            },
            {
                "id":"2",
                "country":"Cards"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

This will iterate through those results

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.products[0], function (i, v) {
        // etc
    });
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/68e0ctrh/1/)**

Comment: Thanks dude I got the idea of Array contains my Array which contains the Array of my data now.
Appreciate your response.